# How to change url without refreshing to the next page using Next Js useRouter?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-router

I am using Next.js and I want to know how to change the url on the same page without refresh it. I am using shallow=true but it still render to the next page.

This is my code:

```
<Tabs>
   <Tab href='test/1' label='Sample Exam'/>
   <Tab href='test/1/exam' label='Test Exam'/>
</Tabs>
<TabPanel value={tabvalue} index={0}>
   <SampleComponent />
</TabPanel> 
<TabPanel value={tabvalue} index={1}>
   <TestComponent />
</TabPanel>
```

This is the logic but does not work

```
    const [tabValue, setTabValue] = React.useState(0);
    const router = useRouter();
    const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<{}>, newValue: number) => {
        setTabValue(newValue);
        useEffect(() => {
            router.replace('/test/1', '/test/1/exam', { shallow: true});
        }, []);
    };
```

I have already test router.push it does not work and windows replace state is a bad idea. The tabs will look like this.

```
     Sample Exam          |        Test Exam
```

if you click sample exam it will show the Sample Details same with the Test but it must be on the same page.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Old post, but someone may find it useful:

The problem is, that you can not shallow route `'/test/1'` to `'/test/1/exam'`, because nextjs uses file system based routing.
Inside your pages directory, `'test/1'` will point to `test/1/index.js` or if you are using dynamic paths it is `test/[id].js`.
However `'/test/1/exam'` will point to `test/1/exam/index.js` or, in case of dynamic paths, it can be `test/[id]/exam/index.js`.
These two files are not on a different level, thus shallow routing won't work.

You can try add a query, e.g.: `test/1?show=exam`, because that can be handled with only 1 file: `test/[id].js`. Shallow routing will work this way.

Other way is is to display something in case of the sample exam, too. e.g. instead of using `'test/1'` it could be `'test/1/sample'` and `'test/1/exam'` will remain. In this case, a single file will be able to handle the two separate options with shallow routing: `test/[id]/[slug].js`

See more: https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/introduction AND https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes