# How to do component transitions between pages in NextJS?

Tags: javascript, css, user-interface, next.js

I am trying to make a simple form that slides to the right like this one used by DigitalOcean when you click on "Sign up using email": https://cloud.digitalocean.com/registrations/new.

The transition itself is pretty easy, what caught my attention is that they use 2 separate routes for this, the first one under /new and the other one under /email. These 2 seem to be separate pages and not just 2 different states to which a route is programmatically added, how can I do this in NextJS?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the feature that you're looking for is [shallow routing](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/shallow-routing).

From the Docs:

> Shallow routing allows you to change the URL without running data
> fetching methods again, that includes getServerSideProps,
> getStaticProps, and getInitialProps.
>
> You'll receive the updated pathname and the query via the router
> object (added by useRouter or withRouter), without losing state.

Note, however, that:

> [s]hallow routing only works for URL changes in the current page.

See also:

- [next/router - router.push()](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#routerpush)
- [Dynamic Routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes)
- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70930345/20313186) by [@metaaa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15035757/metaaa) may also shed some light re implementation.

Best of luck and happy coding!